# icecast intro file - can it be a remote script?

Tags: icecast

So I am wondering if anyone on here knows if the intro file that is in icecast has to be a audio file, as what I want to do is have it load a script that then loads the intro mp3.

I am wondering if this can be done and if anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR - no

[Icecast documentation on this topic](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#mountsettings)

> #### intro
>
> An optional value which will specify the file those contents will be
>   sent to new listeners when they connect but before the normal stream
>   is sent. Make sure the format of the file specified matches the
>   streaming format. The specified file[name] is appended to [the] webroot [path] before
>   being opened.

There are some tricks you could possibly play:

- Replace the file from time to time
- Trigger the replacement based on a url-auth request. This may *not* be 100% reliable in situations where many clients connect in close succession.
- Patch the Icecast source code
- Pay one of the companies that have patched Icecast in similar ways for hosting.